# Why the background color not displaying?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to make [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bLujxz4z/) of html and css. I give background color to **div** it works fine. However, when I give position property  to its children the background color property doesn't work. Why?

Example when I remove this property in **ul** the background color display.But when I apply this property to **ul** then background color does not display why?

```
ul{
position:absolute;
right:0px;
}
```

**code**

```
<div style="background:blue;position:relative">
<ul><li><a></a>aa</li><li><a>h</a></li></ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With all of the div's contents positioned absolutely, the div doesn't actually have a height. You will need to manually set the height of the div.

A similar thing happens if the contents of the div are all floated; however, a workaround for this is to use `overflow:hidden;` on the containing div. You can see a demo of this on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLujxz4z/2/). It actually produces the result that I assume you were trying to achieve.

```
<div style="background:blue;position:relative;overflow:hidden;">
    <ul><li><a></a>aa</li><li><a>h</a></li></ul>
</div>



ul{
    float:right
}
```